# I’m only getting one childNode when appending nodes elsewhere

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with most of the content generated from an XML file. The generated content is a table with the first cell in each row being an expanding element:

```html
<details><summary>...</summary>...</details>
```

I’m trying to change the content of some `<summary>` into links as they are being generated. The content of the `<summary>` may be text or an `<img>` and text. Since `appendChild` doesn’t allow me to append a `NodeList`, my alternative for this was to cycle through the `<summary>` children and add them to the link, then append the link to a replacement `<summary>`. Unfortunately, the `for` loop never accessed the second child.

```js
for (var j = 0; j < curSummary.childNodes.length; j++) {
  // ...
}
```

I verified that `curSummary.childNodes.length` is actually `2` but the loop only ever executed once for each `<summary>`. Putting an `alert` in to display the value of the loop variable showed it was only ever `0`.

```js
alert('there are' + curSummary.childNodes.length + ' nodes');

for (var j = 0; j < curSummary.childNodes.length; j++) { 
  alert('appending child node ' + j + ' of ' + curSummary.childNodes.length);
}
```

Apart from omitting the text, the code worked. The summary showed up with `<img>` as a link. Just to be clear, both the image and text are displayed when there isn’t a link.

And no, I’m not changing the value of the loop variable nor issuing a “break” anywhere in the loop.

Comment: [I can't reproduce that](https://jsfiddle.net/x3fmra7d/). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [`childNodes`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) is a _live_ collection. If you append these nodes elsewhere, they disappear from the `NodeList` _as you’re iterating_. Related: [Strange behavior when iterating over HTMLCollection from getElementsByClassName](/q/15562484/4642212). Technically a dupe of [AppendChild in for loop adds every second child?](/q/69677367/4642212), but the answer isn’t very good at explaining why this happens.

Comment: Tangentially related to [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](/q/10693845/4642212) (see solution in answer).

Comment: So I should be iterating through appending the firstChild until childNodes == 0. Thanks Sebastian.